# Multiple application portal in ASP.NET MVC (migrating from ColdFusion)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, coldfusion

We have an existing portal built in ColdFusion (custom Fusebox based design) and are looking to move to ASP.NET MVC.  This portal has modules which are really independent applications which can be added and removed as needed.  We would like to start building a new portal with ASP.NET MVC but I'm not sure how this would work due to the following concerns:

A) Everything we do in the database in our current ColdFusion portal is done through SQL stored procedures (many of the select based ones returning more than one result set).  Our policy is that there is no generated or adhoc SQL in our application (everything is done through stored procedures) and we want to keep it that way.  When I look at MVC, it seems the model tries to abstract everything out.

B) In our current system, modules are included using simple cfinclude statements to the module/application folder.  They have their own database(s) (and sometimes separate SQL servers) as well; the main portal core runs all through the same server and set of databases.  This allows developers to work on a specific module/application without affecting any other part of the application (or even having access to it).  If we have a MVC portal, how can developers work on individual modules in it?

C) Our current portal uses a single login which then determines what modules/applications they can view.  If we want to continue down that road, does that require we have a single 'project' in Visual Studio that encompasses the main pieces of the portal and each module/application?

I would appreciate any tips or hints on how to get started or if anyone knows of any open-source portals that are doing something similar that we could get some ideas from which to base our portal.

Comment: Port? No...You would be better served using it as a model and rewrite it from scratch on .NET and use C# with Razor MVC 5 thingy.

Comment: We are definitely not wanting to port.  It's a re-write of everything except possibly some stored procedures.

Comment: (voting to close as it's not the sort of thing that can be answered sensibly in a few paragraphs on a website. You probably need to get some ppl in to do an assessment of what needs doing here).

Comment: As @AdamCameron said, this cannot be answered in a few paragraphs because of its wide scope. It's like saying that I want to build an application tell me how.:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brad,

I once asked an old man for directions to someplace on a country road. He scratched his chin for a moment and then replied solemnly, "You can't get there from here."  I'm afraid you may be in the same boat. If you wish to hue closely to MVC *and* have individual modules with code separation *and* retain the flexibility of your data access layer without abstraction - you are probably going to pull out your hair. Fusebox, while aged and more or less "procedural" in spite of how it seems is dictating these rules for you. Fusebox is in itself a pattern of developing and your habits have conformed to it. .NET MVC (or just MVC in general) is a quite different pattern and as such will require that you conform to different rules.

Of the items above specifically I would say that:

A) there's no reason you cannot continue to use your stored procs and still remain MVC - it will require more custom programming than you would like - but your DAO layer doesn't care what's developing the data on the other side. It's job is returning datasets and results etc. But it will not look like ORM or whatever - it will need custom calls to the DB in your objects.

B) I don't think this is feasible.

C) Again - I think moving to MVC would preclude this as an option unless you want to specifically enable dev access at the *file level* - which sounds like a recipe for disaster to me.

Let me know if you need help maintaining the CF FB app while you are transitioning, or if you need help making this migration. Our teams do a great deal of this sort of work.

Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark.  It definitely seems this is going to be a significant challenge.  What about abandoning the idea of using the MVC design.  Does that change any of the answers in any significant way or is more just a shift in complete code design and structure when moving from ColdFusion to .NET.

Comment: Yes of course - if you choose to create a framework that mimics the pattern of FB then you could pretty easily follow your existing SDLC. Years ago there was even a .NET FB framework out there - though many versions ago. The caution is (as you probably already know) that you would be creating a _non MVC_ pattern and likely doing things in a non ".NET" way. So it will keep your SDLC from being disrupted but it may not be an improvment.